# hive timestamp not converting as expected

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

My input timestamp is like

> 06/08/2017 19:02:03 EDT

and I am looking to convert that to

> 2017-06-08 19:02:03

I am trying to run the below query but it is not converting as expected

```
select 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('06/08/2017 19:02:03 EDT', 'MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss z'))
```

Output: `2017-01-01 18:02:03`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('06/08/2017 19:02:03 EDT', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss')) ;
```

- Changed YYYY to yyyy

Edit:

If your server is in EDT timezone below query should work, otherwise output will be in server local timezone.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('06/08/2017 19:02:03 EDT', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss z'), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') ;
```

Comment: What do you mean "as it is for PDT"? The timezone is dependent upon Java's locale on the server itself

Comment: PDT stands for - Pacific Standard Time (Daylight)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Yes, I know. I meant that you should keep the `z` as it is part of the time format being parsed. There's no reason to remove it because it stands for PDT

Comment: @sachin: This works as expected even without `z`, but it makes more sense to keep the `z`.

Comment: Refer the below wiki for more details -

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions